# HM-10 returns Euro symbol

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno, hm-10

I am working with HM-10 copy CC4A-1 module. I connected it with Arduino Uno R3 after struggling a lot it got connected. I performed some AT Commands using Arduino Serial Monitor suddenly it stops working after executing AT+RENEW command. I also tried to perform AT+BAUD `command but it returned error before executing AT+RENEW.`

[This is the output of Arduino Serial Monitor while sending data from HMBLE Terminal Android Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAEFn.png)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(2, 3); //RX|TX


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600); // default baud rate
  while(!Serial); //if it is an Arduino Micro
  Serial.println("AT commands: ");
}

void loop(){
  //read from the HM-10 and print in the Serial
  if(BTSerial.available())
    Serial.write(BTSerial.read());

  //read from the Serial and print to the HM-10
  if(Serial.available())
    BTSerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

[This is what is sent from Android Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0O47.png)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the serial output, I would guess the baud rate didn't change whenever you sent the "AT+RENEW" command. The reason I suspect this is by looking at the binary equivalent of "€", which is "10000000".  UART data is sent active low, so it looks to be detecting the beginning of a byte, however, the timing of the rest of the high-low signals is wrong.  I would try connecting the module at whatever baud rate you had it set at before the AT+RENEW command.

The official HM-10 behavior is the module should return to a baud rate of 9600.  However, I've noticed occasionally it needs to be reset by powering it off, then on.  Or, sending "AT+RESET".

That being said, if it is an HM-10 clone, who knows what's really going on in the firmware.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply. I tried resetting the module using specified pin in datasheet but nothing happens apart from this i also tried to changing baud rate when my module was working but it gave me error which means baud rate should be 9600 which was default now if i send "ASD" from android application it shows four "EURO" signs in serial monitor one more thing i can't execute AT Commands don't know why whenever i sent AT from Arduino Serial Monitor nothing happens :-(

Comment: It sounds like you might have to chalk it up as a failed clone. One thing you might check is the Arduino serial monitor is set to no line feed character.  The HM-10 requires exclusion of CR or LF chars, whereas the CC4A-1 requires them.

Comment: I tried every option from Arduino Serial Monitor but no luck is there anyway to diagnose whether RX & TX of HM-10 is fine or gone? It seems i have destroyed RX or TX because of which it is not responding to AT Commands?

Comment: There are probably lots of ways to diagnose if it is dead.  I usually use a logic-sniffer.  The Open-Bench Logic Sniffer is what I use and it's around $50.  http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Open_Bench_Logic_Sniffer

Answer (score 0):

After googling a lot since finally i found the solution... I was working on ESP8266 module and i tried to change its baud rate too and it stopped working i googled for command which i executed lastly and found that wrong command corrupted module firmware i searched and recovered ESP8266 by reloading firmware in it

Above works as hint for me i did same thing with my HM-10 Module and uploaded orignal HM-10 Module firmware using the link below and finally it is working like a charm really excited to continue my project again anyone facing same problem give below link a try

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=393655.0